# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement when saving to an access database

Tags: vb.net, dataset

Newbie here, I'm having a problem saving the dataset into the database file. I cannot find the INSERT INTO Statement to correct, or is it really not included in the code? How do I solve this. Thanks everyone!

```
Private Sub btnRead_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) -
Handles btnRead.Click

    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

    con.Open()

    sql = "SELECT * FROM DTR"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "DTR")

    Dim strFileNameAndPath As String = txtFileLoc.Text

    'codes assigning data's into arrays for use by database 



                    'Create rows on database
                    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
                    Dim newrow As DataRow = ds.Tables("DTR").NewRow

                    newrow("EmpNo") = empNo
                    newrow("EmpName") = empName
                    newrow("WorkDate") = workDate
                    newrow("Day") = workDay
                    newrow("TimeIn1") = in1
                    newrow("TimeOut1") = out1
                    newrow("TimeIn2") = in2
                    newrow("TimeOut2") = out2
                    newrow("NextDay") = nextDay
                    newrow("HoursWork") = hrsWork

                    ds.Tables("DTR").Rows.Add(newrow)

                    Me.Validate()
                    da.Update(ds.Tables("DTR"))  'ERROR APPEARS HERE

                Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                    MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & "is not valid and will be skipped.")
                End Try

            End While

            DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False

            DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 4

            DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "Date"
            DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Date"
            DataGridView1.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "WorkDate"

            DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "Day"
            DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Day"
            DataGridView1.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "Day"

            DataGridView1.Columns(2).Name = "Time In"
            DataGridView1.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Time IN"
            DataGridView1.Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "TimeIn1"

            DataGridView1.Columns(3).Name = "Time Out"
            DataGridView1.Columns(3).HeaderText = "Time OUT"
            DataGridView1.Columns(3).DataPropertyName = "TimeOut2"

            DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("DTR")

        End Using

    con.Close()
    MsgBox("Connection is closed")

End Sub
```

Here is the stack trace for the error...

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was ErrorCode=-2147217900
  Message=Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
  Source=Microsoft Office Access Database Engine
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatusErrors(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatus(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[] dataRows, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateFromDataTable(DataTable dataTable, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataTable dataTable)
       at WindowsApplication17.Form1.btnRead_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\users\arlo\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication17\Form1.vb:line 125
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at WindowsApplication17.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: What is the error that 'APPEARS HERE' ??!

Comment: "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"

Comment: Well that's not a lot to go on, is it?!  Have you got a stack trace or any kind of detail from the database engine?